# Tool for clustering and cleansing data set

Tags: clustering, data-cleaning, tools

I have a large-ish data set (400K records) composed of two fields (both strings). I am looking for a tool that will enable me to cluster the data e.g. around the first column, either using exact matches or some kind of string proximity function like Levenshtein distance. I would also like to be able to find all duplicate records and merge them into one.

OpenRefine looks ideal for my purposes but it is so slow when clustering my data or creating a text facet that it is unusable. Apparently this is a [known issue](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/672).

I looked around but couldn't find another tool that would enable me to explore a data set of this size, cluster, eliminate dupes, look for anomalies, etc. Can anyone recommend something that might fit the bill?

Comment: you may also want to consider moving your question to [the software recommendation SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

- What do you mean to cluster data around a column? You can use standard clustering models, such as **k-Means clustering** or **Gaussian Mixture Models** for an exploratory analysis of your dataset. However, I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, please let me know.
- I often study a new dataset by employing some **dimensionality reduction** technique. The most common is **PCA**, but I don't recommend it since it can extract only latent factors that are linearly associated with your variables. You can use **t-SNE** models (available in sklearn), or, if you are familiar with Deep Learning, with **Autoencoders for dimensionality reduction**. Once your dataset is compressed/reduced, you can observe how different values-factors are distributed on it.
  Dimensionality reduction is also very important in case your dataset suffers from high multicollinearity.
- You can remove duplicates using `pandas`' `drop_duplicates()` function, explained [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Hope this helps, otherwise let me know.

Comment: His data are strings. You can't use kmeans nor GMM nor PCA nor tSNE on this data.

Comment: I can definitely analyze the data in code. I was expecting that there would be some good visual tools for doing this, which would greatly accelerate the process. I'm surprised that I haven't been able to find anything (besides OpenRefine which is, as I said, way too slow to be usable with my data). Maybe I'll write my own...

Answer (score 1):

OpenRefine is the tool that you need. The clustering functionality is accessible without creating a text facet by using the "Cluster & Edit" function (under "Edit Cells") will take you directly to the clustering dialog. The clustering itself is actually pretty fast, but, until recently, there were scalability issues with displaying large numbers of clusters/items, but last summer [I introduced a cap](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/pull/2996) on the number of choices displayed which dramatically speeds things up. It went from ~200 seconds to ~10 seconds for my test case of 41K clusters containing 118K values. This will be available in OpenRefine 3.5, but in the meantime you can grab our [snapshot releases](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine-snapshot-releases/releases).

If you do outgrow OpenRefine, you could implement the same algorithms that we use internally. String similarity libraries should be easy to find for the language of your choice, then the "only" problem is to figure out how to block your records so that your O(n^2) pairwise distance measurements complete in a reasonable amount of time AND you don't miss any valid matches. Because this is different for different data sets, OpenRefine gives the user control over choosing the blocking strategy, but for a fixed data set, you may be able to choose just one that works best.

Obviously, the degenerate case where the first field is the same is even easier and could even be managed using *nix tools.